# Jesus Christ purchased us with his blood - parties involved

Tags: atonement, blood-of-christ

According to these verses and others, God/Jesus purchased/redeemed us with his blood

> **Revelation 5:9**
>
> And they sung a new song, saying, Thou art worthy to take the book,
>   and to open the seals thereof: for thou wast slain, and hast redeemed
>   us to God by thy blood out of every kindred, and tongue, and people,
>   and nation;
>
> **Acts 20:28**
>
> Keep watch over yourselves and all the flock of which the Holy Spirit
>   has made you overseers. Be shepherds of the church of God, which he
>   bought with his own blood

Who was the receiving party -  I mean the blood?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a misunderstanding of terms on your part.

Remember first that our English translations often miss nuances in translation.  Words carry different meanings.  These phrases are generally understood to mean that Jesus *paid the price* for our sins.  That ***can*** certainly connote the idea of a purchase in the normal sense, as in "I paid for my groceries".  However, it's generally understood in the same sense as a criminal *paying the price* for his crimes, as in going to jail, being executed, etc.

Unless I'm mistaken (and I'd be interested to see references that say otherwise) there isn't any major group in Christianity that actually views these as speaking as a transaction with a buyer and a seller.

Rather, it's an expression of the fact that there is a price attached to sin.  It's a price we sinners can never pay, and since we can't, Christ paid it for us.

Comment: May be it's English, the word "Redeem" means retrieving something that was lost [with/without a price - but the bible mentioned it's with a price] - as you pointed out, that is the picture on my mind

Comment: There are definitely certain soteriologies - such as satisfaction theory or some forms of substitutionary atonement that would argue the price was owed to God or the devil, respectively.

Comment: @AffableGeek The theory owing God conforms with the scripture in some way - it is God we sinned against, it is God who has the penalty and somebody paid for that instead. I am open to the other options too.